# How to solve the recurrence relation of $f_n(x)=A_n(a,b)x+B_n(a,b)f(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$$f(f(x))=ax+bf(x)$$

$$f(f(f(x)))=f_3(x)=af(x)+b(ax+bf(x))=abx+(a+b^2)f(x)$$

$$f(f(f(f(x))))=f_4(x)=abf(x)+(a+b^2)(ax+bf(x))=(a^2+ab^2)x+(2ab+b^3)f(x)$$

$$f_n(x)=A_n(a,b)x+B_n(a,b)f(x)$$

$$f_n(f(x))=A_n(a,b)f(x)+B_n(a,b)(ax+bf(x))$$

$$f_n(f(x))=aB_n(a,b)x+(bB_n(a,b)+A_n(a,b))f(x))$$

$$f_{n+1}(x)=A_{n+1}(a,b)x+B_{n+1}(a,b)f(x)$$

---

$A_2(a,b)=a$

$B_2(a,b)=b$

$A_3(a,b)=ab$

$B_3(a,b)=a+b^2$

$$A_{n+1}(a,b)=aB_n(a,b)$$

$$B_{n+1}(a,b)=A_n(a,b)+bB_n(a,b)$$

---

$$A_{n+2}(a,b)=aB_{n+1}(a,b)=aA_n(a,b)+abB_n(a,b))=aA_n(a,b)+bA_{n+1}(a,b)$$

$$A_{n+2}(a,b)=aA_n(a,b)+bA_{n+1}(a,b)$$

How can be found the closed form expression of $A_{n}(a,b)$?

Thanks a lot for answers

Comment: You want $A_2 = a$ and $B_2=b$. Otherwise your formular'd be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it like:

1. $\frac1aA_{n+1}(a,b)=B_n(a,b)$
2. $B_{n+1}(a,b)=A_n(a,b)+\frac baA_{n+1}(a,b)$
3. $A_{n+2}(a,b)=aB_{n+1}(a,b)=a(A_n(a,b)+\frac baA_{n+1}(a,b))=aA_n(a,b)+bA_{n+1}(a,b)$

Now $A_{n+2}(a,b)=bA_{n+1}(a,b)+aA_n(a,b)$ looks like a [Lucas Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence) $U_n(b,-a)$. Equation (33) in the linked [MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasSequence.html) gives a closed form:
$$
A_n(a,b)=U_n(b,-a)=2^{1-n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k+1}b^{n-2k-1}(b^2+4a)^k
$$

Comment: Could you please check upper limit of  summation?

Comment: @math thanks for spotting...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my solution for the problem

$$f(f(x))=ax+bf(x)$$

$f(x)=rx$ is a solution of the equation.

$$r^2x=(a+br)x$$

$$r^2-br-a=0$$

$$r_1=\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2}$$
$$r_2=\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2}$$

$$f_n(x)=r^nx$$

$$f_n(x)=A_n(a,b)x+B_n(a,b)f(x)=(A_n(a,b)+rB_n(a,b))x$$

$$A_n(a,b)+(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2})B_n(a,b)=(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2})^n$$

$$A_n(a,b)+(\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2})B_n(a,b)=(\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2})^n$$

$$B_n(a,b)=\cfrac{(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2})^n-(\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2})^n}{\sqrt{b^2+4a}}$$

$$A_{n+1}(a,b)=aB_n(a,b)=a\cfrac{(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2})^n-(\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2})^n}{\sqrt{b^2+4a}}$$

$$A_{n}(a,b)=a\cfrac{(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2})^{n-1}-(\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2})^{n-1}}{\sqrt{b^2+4a}}$$